# finding the inverse of $a \sinh b*x +c*x$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-function

Does the function 
$$y(x) = cx + a \sinh (bx) $$
have an inverse function $x=x(y)$ and if yes, what is it?

The part 
$$y(x) = a \sinh(bx)$$
can easily be inverted to
$$ x(y) = asinh(y/a)/b$$

For $c>0$ the function is strictly monotonic,
so by just looking at the graph I would assume an inverse should exist.

Comment: If $c=-10$ and $a=b=1$, then the inverse is not definded for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So for arbitrary values of $a,b,c$ we can reject that the inverse does exist for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. But if you choose specific values of $a,b,c$ the inverse does exist for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But I highly doubt that you can state the inverse for non trivial choices of $a,b,c$ as a closed form solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have now updated the question, a solution for positive c is what I was actualy looking for.

Comment: As I said it is very unlikely that you will be able to get a closed form solution for the inverse. What do you plan to do with the inverse?

Comment: Use both functions in a simulation tool, which is capable of simplifying the system of equations if inverses and or derivatives are given. A discussion is here: https://github.com/iea-annex60/modelica-annex60/issues/635#issuecomment-273116120, I have also asked two more related questions in the last days.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2100016/solve-system-of-two-trigonometric-equations

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096077/invert-regularisation-function

Comment: Would a taylor series of the inverse function help you?

Comment: The function and its inverse just have to be consistent numerically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52136/discussion-between-mryoumath-and-matth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb: if the unknown is both outside and inside trig/log/exp functions, there is no closed form inverse (unless in terms of purpose-defined special functions).

So no... just looking at your expression, seeing $x$ in a linear term and inside $\sinh$, the only way to do this is solving it numerically.